# How do I create a better drag and drop .BAT file that processes as many files as I select?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, vlc-media-player, drag-and-drop

How do I create a better drag and drop .BAT file that processes as many files as I select?

The purpose of this batch file is to convert any file with sound on it (mp3, ogg, mp4, etc) to a wav. I want to be able to convert more than 9 at a time.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "%~1"
ECHO "%~2"
ECHO "%~3"
ECHO "%~4"
ECHO "%~5"
ECHO "%~6"
ECHO "%~7"
ECHO "%~8"
ECHO "%~9"
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~1" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~1.wav"} vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~2" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~2.wav"} vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~3" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~3.wav"} vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~4" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~4.wav"} vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~5" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~5.wav"} vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~6" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~6.wav"} vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~7" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~7.wav"} vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~8" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~8.wav"} vlc://quit
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%~9" --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst="%~9.wav"} vlc://quit
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I want to be able to convert more than 9 at a time.

You can convert up to `255`:

> You can get the value of any argument using a % followed by it's numerical position on the command line. The first item passed is always %1 the second item is always %2 and so on.
>
> %* in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 ...%255)
> only arguments %1 to %9 can be referenced by number.

Source: [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Use the `shift` command to make life easier for yourself:

> Only parameters %1 to %9 can be referenced by number, but it is possibly to pass more than 9 arguments. The SHIFT command provides a way of accessing these additional argument values.

Source: [Shift - reposition command line parameters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html)

See the above link for examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "vlcConvert=C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"

for %%a in (%*) do "%vlcConvert%" %%a --no-random --sout-file-format --sout=#transcode{acodec=s16l,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=%%a.wav} vlc://quit

pause
```